# Moving CSS declarations inline - coding e-newsletters

Tags: html, css

Do you know of any tools that can take a set of CSS styles and move them inline to the appropriate HTML tags?

Many email clients don't read the `<style>` declarations, which is why the email-marketing tool I use ([Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)) does this as part of their **import** functionality.

I'm now working with other software and would like to be able to do this with a 3rd party tool. I could always code directly with inline style declarations but this can get very messy.

**So, does anyone know of such tool?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go.

http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Comment: Awesome - it's the same one as Campaign Monitor. That's perfect.

Comment: @Marko, I've used this one before and it works quite well. Good luck.